# Initializing a vector from a text file

Tags: c++, string, file-io, vector, formatted-input

I am attempting to write a program which can read in a text file, and store each word in it as an entry in a string type vector. I am sure that I am doing this very wrong, but it has been so long since I have tried to do this that I have forgotten how it is done. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> input;
    ifstream readFile;

    vector<string>::iterator it;
    it = input.begin();

    readFile.open("input.txt");

    for (it; ; it++)
    {
        char cWord[20];
        string word;

        word = readFile.get(*cWord, 20, '\n');

        if (!readFile.eof())
        {
            input.push_back(word);
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    cout << "Vector Size is now %d" << input.size();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This has never been asked before

Comment: I'm kind of missing the question in this question. What goes wrong when you try your current code? Also, part of the specification is missing. Is every word guaranteed to be in a separate line in you file?

Comment: Is there a reason why you use the array `cWord` to store the word, while you could read directly into `word` variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> input;
    ifstream readFile("input.txt");
    copy(istream_iterator<string>(readFile), {}, back_inserter(input));
    cout << "Vector Size is now " << input.size();
}
```

Or, shorter:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream readFile("input.txt");
    cout << "Vector Size is now " << vector<string>(istream_iterator<string>(readFile), {}).size();
}
```

I'm not going to explain, because there's about a zillion explanations on StackOverflow already :)

Comment: Not trying to be the grumpy old guy, but if there are a zillion explanations already, wouldn't the right course of action be to mark this as a duplicate?

Comment: @us2012 Yes. But it was quicker to just write it up. A zillion duplicates sadly implies half a zillion bad examples, and I didn't feel like sifting. But, feel free to close as dupe !

Comment: I didn't realize that there was already a lot of explanations, I was possibly unable to come up with proper search terms. Thank you, however for answering.

Answer (score 6):

One of the many possible ways is a simple:

```
std::vector<std::string> words;
std::ifstream file("input.txt");

std::string word;
while (file >> word) {
    words.push_back(word);
}
```

operator `>>` takes care of only words divided by whitespaces (including new-lines) being read.

---

And in case you would be reading it by lines, you might also need to explicitly handle empty lines:

```
std::vector<std::string> lines;
std::ifstream file("input.txt");

std::string line;
while ( std::getline(file, line) ) {
    if ( !line.empty() )
        lines.push_back(line);
}
```